# Android: Horizontal View Swiping and Switching Activities

Tags: android

I am new in Android Development. and going to create a new app. in which i need following type of navigation in Android 2.2 and above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwG1Z.png

I saw a tutorial at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

But he is Only Swiping Pages. There are no Tabs like In Above image. And also he is updating some text view but i want to switch between activities or layouts.

I have tried many things. ActionBarSherlock it created many errors.

The thing I need is

developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

developer.android.com/shareables/training/EffectiveNavigation.zip

In Above file CollectionDemoActivity is the thing Which I actually looking for Android 2.2 and above.

If someone have project like this please share code.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://bitbucket.org/owentech/abstabsviewpager) is a sample project for using ActionBarSherlock with a ViewPager to have tabs & swipe together. It works, I've used it.

Comment: At Last I found for which i was searching. May be Some one else needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Jake Wharton's other project, [Viewpagerindicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com). It provides the functionality that you are after. And [here](http://droidista.blogspot.se/2012/08/making-actionbarsherlock-and.html) is a tutorial for using them together. There are also some excellent guides over at [Styling Android](http://stylingandroid.com/).